# Reading last error message in log file

Tags: python, popen, stderr, seek

In Python 2.7 I have the following code inside certain loop

```
file = open("log.txt", 'a+')
last_position = file.tell()
subprocess.Popen(["os_command_producing_error"], stderr = file)
file.seek(last_position)
error = file.read()
print(error) # example of some action with the error
```

The intention is that the error that was just given by `stderr` gets, say printed, while `file` is keeping the whole record.

I am a beginner in Python and I am not clear what happens in the `stderr = file`.

My problem is that `error` keeps being empty, even though errors keep getting logged in the `file`.

Could someone explain why?

I have tried adding closing and opening the file again, or `file.flush()` right after the `subprocess` line. But still the same effect.

**Edit:** The code in the answer below makes sense to me and it seems to work for for the author of that post. For me (in Windows) it is not working. It gives an empty `err` and an empty file `log.txt`. If I run it line by line (e.g. debugging) it does work. How to understand and solve this problem?

**Edit:** I changed the `Popen` with `call` and now it works. I guess `call` waits for the `subprocess` to finish in order to continue with the script.

Comment: try add ``file.close()`` at the script end.

Comment: And by the way, are you using **Python 2.4**?

Comment: OK, try use `sys.stderr = file` instead `stderr = file`

Comment: Maybe my comment isn't so clear, let me post an answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can flush the file first, before moving the file pointer. But I'd go with close and reopen.

Comment: @Evert I find a problem: when raise the error, then the program will exit. so we can't flush or close the file.

Comment: @Evert And I don't know why ``try`` doesn't work .

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense. What error do you want to raise? What `try` statement (I don't see any)? If there is more context to it than the above, it might be good to show it.

Comment: Given your initial code, without a try-except clause, why didn't subprocess raise an exception in the first place why you tried to run that code? Because I think it should, but you claim your code made it through (with an non-existing command) to the end. Which makes me think that command was either successfully executed, or no attempt to execute was made by the underlying shell. In both cases, the log file would not be updated, and `error` would indeed be empty.

Comment: @Evert My code is inside a `try:` and inside a loop too. I didn't include them here. The OS command for sure writes to stderr and also to stdout.

Comment: @Evert However the ``try-except`` is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` is empty because you are reading too soon before the process has a chance to write anything to the file. `Popen()` starts a new process; it does not wait for it to finish.

`call()` is equivalent to `Popen().wait()` that does wait for the child process to exit that is why you should see non-empty `error` in this case (if the subprocess does write anything to `stderr`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

with open("log.txt", 'a+') as file:
   subprocess.check_call(["os_command_producing_error"], stderr=file)
   error = file.read()
print(error)
```

You should be careful with [mixing buffered (`.read()`) and unbuffered I/O (`subprocess`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22417159/4279).

You don't need the external file here, to read the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

error = subprocess.check_output(["os_command_producing_error"],
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(error)
```

It merges stderr and stdout and returns the output.

If you don't want to capture stdout then to get only stderr, you could use `Popen.communicate()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["os_command_producing_error"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
error = p.communicate()[1]
print(error)
```

You could both capture stderr and append it to a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

error = bytearray()
p = subprocess.Popen(["os_command_producing_error"],
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
with p.stderr as pipe, open('log.txt', 'ab') as file:
    for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
        error += line
        file.write(line)
p.wait()
print(error)
```

See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Comment: Thank you. There are some commands there that I think I will not be able to use, like `check_output` or `with`. I have Python 3.. and 2.7 in my laptop, but I think I will need to run the script in some places with 2.4.

Comment: The third code snippet should work. I think I had tried that one at some point but got rid of it because I thought the command was supposed to communicate through `stdout` and I wasn't seeing the messages in `p.communicate()[0]`. If I knew I had only to change it to `p.communicate()[1]` ...

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy: your question says *Python 2.7*. The code in my answer works without any changes on Python 2.7 and 3. It can be adapted to work on Python 2.4 (that also has `subprocess` module) e.g., here's [how to emulate `check_output()` on earlier Python versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924457/4279). You should mention explicitly in your question what python versions you need to support.

Answer (score 0):

Try these following codes:

```
file = open("log.txt", 'a+')
sys.stderr = file
last_position = file.tell()
try:
    subprocess.call(["os_command_producing_error"])
except:
    file.close()
    err_file = open("log.txt", 'r')
    err_file.seek(last_position)
    err = err_file.read()
    print err
    err_file.close()
```

`sys.stderr` map the standard error message like `sys.stdout`(map standard output)  and `sys.stdin`(map standard input).

And this will map the standard error to `file`. So all of the standard error will be write to the file `log.txt`.

Comment: Now it is not writing anything in log.txt

Comment: My Python is ``2.7.10``,  and the code can work. Would you try to use `file = open("log.txt", 'w')` instead `file = open("log.txt", 'a+')`?

Comment: Your code works. But the important part is to latter read that **last** error message from the file and do things with it. I have a `last_position = file.tell()` before the subprocess to know where we were in the file before the subprocess call. Then a `file.seek(last_position)` after it, and `err = file.read()` following. This is to get the last error message in `err`.

Comment: Yes, just tried. `print err` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Hum...maybe I should close the file and open it in `r` mode again. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: You might consider different underlying OSes. Perhaps one OS let's subprocess throw an error before the underlying shell sends an error message. Seems unlikely, but unless you know the intrinsics of subprocess, I could potentially see that happen.

Comment: @Evert Hum...I'm on Arch Linux.

Comment: Inserting `file.close(); file = open("log.txt", 'r')` as the first two lines of the `except:` and empty `err` and empty file.

Comment: Sorry. that still gives empty err and empty log.txt It is weird.

Comment: Gosh, which system are you on?

Comment: I am using Windows. Does it work properly in Linux? The code totally makes sense, except that I don't know what happens with stderr in the subprocess.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on Arch Linux and the code work perfectly. I don't understand why doesn't the code work on windows.

Comment: Ha! If I give it a `time.sleep(5)` it works. The solution might have to do with coercing somehow the OS to pass the stderr to the file.

Comment: Great! I understand: because Linux will write the error message to file right now, but Windows will wait some time. And let me edit my answer :)